# Out-of-the-box pool mining solution

Tags: mining-pools

It is very hard to find an open source free solution to build a public mining pool.  Is there any pre-made, out-of-the-box solutions one can buy?

Answer (score 1):

I would disagree that it is hard to find open source solutions, there are three pieces of software that need to be combined to create a mining pool.

1. [bitcoind](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) (or litecoind etc)
2. Pool software ([pushpool](https://github.com/jgarzik/pushpool) or [stratum](https://github.com/slush0/stratum-mining))
3. Web front end ([SimpleCoin](https://github.com/simplecoin/simplecoin), [mmcFE](https://github.com/Greedi/mmcFE), [MPOS](https://github.com/TheSerapher/php-mpos))

I am unaware of any commercial out-of-the-box solutions at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [p2pool](https://github.com/forrestv/p2pool) which is open source.